# Dynamically selecting the column to select from the row itself in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-sql

I have a SQL Server table with some data as follows. The number of P columns are fixed but there will be too many columns. There will be multiple columns in the fashion like S1, S2 etc

| Id | SelectedP | P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | P5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P2 | 3 | 8 | 4 | 15 | 7 |
| 2 | P1 | 0 | 2 | 6 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | P3 | 1 | 15 | 2 | 1 | 11 |
| 4 | P4 | 3 | 4 | 6 | 2 | 4 |

I need to write a SQL statement which can get the below result. Basically which column that needs to be selected from each row depends upon the SelectedP value in that row itself. The SelectedP contains the column to select for each row.

| Id | SelectedP | Selected-P-Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | P2 | 8 |
| 2 | P1 | 0 |
| 3 | P3 | 2 |
| 4 | P4 | 2 |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *I have a SQL Server 2018 table* actually, that's very unlikely.

Comment: Are there exactly five P columns or is their count variable? For known columns you don't need dynamic SQL at all.

Comment: you can use case statement for Select-P-Value column

Comment: Hi @Arvo The columns will be fixed, but the problem is it will be too many

Comment: @KiranB - Then you have the wrong data-model.  Is changing to a normalised model *(`n` rows per `id`, rather than `n` columns in a single row)* an option for you?  If not, you're just going to have to type them all out, or write code than types them out for you.

Comment: Very simply, your P columns should be one column in a table with a foreign key and N rows per P; your "selected p" is then simply an integer you can use to join and no unwieldy case expressions are needed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need a `CASE` expression...

```
SELECT
  id,
  SelectedP,
  CASE SelectedP
    WHEN 'P1' THEN P1
    WHEN 'P2' THEN P2
    WHEN 'P3' THEN P3
    WHEN 'P4' THEN P4
    WHEN 'P5' THEN P5
  END
    AS SelectedPValue
FROM
  yourTable
```

This will return `NULL` for anything not mentioned in the `CASE` expression.

***EDIT:***

An option with just a ***little*** less typing...

```
SELECT
  id, SelectedP, val  
FROM   
  yourTable AS pvt
UNPIVOT  
(
  val FOR P IN   
  (
    P1,
    P2,
    P3,
    P4,
    P5
  )
)
  AS unpvt
WHERE
  SelectedP = P
```

***NOTE***: If the value of `SelectedP` doesn't exist in the `UNPIVOT`, then the row will not appear at all *(unlike the `CASE` expression which will return a `NULL`)*

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b693738aac0b594cf37410ee5cb15cf5

***EDIT 2:***

I don't know if this will perform much worse than the 2nd option, but this preserves the `NULL` behaviour.

*(The preferred option is still to fix your data-structure.)*

```
SELECT
  id, SelectedP, MAX(CASE WHEN SelectedP = P THEN val END) AS val
FROM   
   yourTable AS pvt
UNPIVOT  
(
  val FOR P IN   
  (
    P1,
    P2,
    P3,
    P4,
    P5
  )
)
  AS unpvt
GROUP BY
  id, SelectedP
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f3f64d2fb6e11fd24d1addbe1e50f020

Comment: The no of columns will be fixed but there will be too many and there are multiple tables like this. So is there any way other than case statements?

Comment: @KiranB - Yes, either fix your data-model or write code that writes the `CASE` expression SQL for you *(termed 'Dynamic SQL')*.